# Angular dynamic select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select

html

```
 <select ng-model="data.retour.selectedAmount" ng-options="c.name for c in getAmountArray(data.retour.amount)">
 </select>
```

Angular

```
 angular.extend($scope, {
    /**
    * Data properties
    * @property view
    */
    data: {
       retour:{}
    }
    });
    getAmountArray: function (amount) {
        amount = parseInt(amount, 10);
        var i, lArray = [];
        for (i = 1; i < (amount + 1); i++) {
            lArray.push({name: i});
        }
        return lArray;
    }
```

With the above code I'm trying to generate a dynamic 1-(amount+1) range dropdown. All seems to work, except for there is an empty value added to the dropdown. Why is this empty value added?

E.G. when amount is 1 the generated list is

```
blank

1
```

and it should be

```
1
```

Comment: You start `i` counter to 1 instead of 0

Comment: ye because i don't want 0 to be displayed. (e.g. if amount is 10 --> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 should be shown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens with `ng-options` when you do not set your `ng-model`. Setting your `$scope.data.retour.selectedAmount` to one of the values returned by `getAmountArray()` should fix it.

You could do that in your controller or simply set it up in the view using `ng-init`. For exmaple, the following selects `1` and eliminates the blank space:

```
<select ng-model="data.retour.selectedAmount" ng-options="c.name as c.name for c in getAmountArray(data.retour.amount)" ng-init="data.retour.selectedAmount = 1"></select>
```

Comment: Doing this doesn't remove the blank option. Could this be because the arraylist is built dynamically?

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't work. I've created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ranru/YrKCS/) that demonstrates it. Did you add the `as c.name` in your `ng-options`?

Comment: You're right it works with your code. But why did you add c.name as ?

Comment: Without `as`, what you have is `label for value in array`. However, since you want to make an initial selection, you need to use `select as label for value in array`. Sometimes, you may want your `select` to be different from `label` - like selecting ids while displaying names as label. Refer to [AngularJS select directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)